# Android get images from gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
```

I am using this intent to images from from gallery but sometimes it shows a different layout.
it should be showing interface like this.

[expected layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTtIM.jpg)

but sometimes it shows this layout and asks to crop the image and i dont get a callback on my activity.

[not expected layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1SZK.jpg)

How can make the intent to get images only using the first layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it should be showing interface like this.

There are ~2.5 billion Android devices, spread over >26,000 models. There are dozens, if not hundreds, of pre-installed apps that will respond to your `Intent`, across those device models. Additionally, there are dozens, if not hundreds, of user-installed apps that will respond to your `Intent`, installed on some of those billions of devices.

Those apps can do what they want, and you do not control what those apps look like.

Comment: ok so the only solution is to make cutom image picker?

Comment: @SameerGangar: If you want a guaranteed consistent UI, then yes. There are [many libraries for that](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/157?sort=created).